# Specify default render method in Portlet (Spring, Liferay)

Tags: spring, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I try to develop portlet for LifeRay portal using Spring Portlet MVC. And in Spring Portlet the default render method is this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class MainController {

    @RenderMapping
    public String myDefaultRenderMethod() { 
        return "defaultView"
    }
}
```

But how I can to change default view method to this:

```
@RenderMapping(params="key=value")
public String myDefaultRenderMethod() { 
    return "defaultView"
}
```

I.e. I want to told to Spring to call default render (at portlet initializing) view with parameter "key=value".

Comment: What you want to do with `key=value` in default render method? Why can't you have both the methods? Are you sure that the `key=value` is delivered to `Portlet` all the time? If not, your `Portlet` will break.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW", params="key=value")
public class MainController {

    @RenderMapping
    public String myDefaultRenderMethod() { 
        return "defaultView"
    }
}
```

Now this controller will invoke only render request contains key parameter with value ='valie'

For other requests you can use smth like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW", params="!=key")
public class AnotherController {
```

Comment: `will invoke only render request contains key parameter with value ='valie'` Yes, but how I can specify this key-value parameter on portlet startup? I.e. I want cause portlet to `callmyDefaultRenderMethod()` at startup, so where I can specify this parameters?

Comment: If you want call some code on portlet initialization, I believe you can use portlet init parameters and bean initialization listener(in spring case) or init method(native portlet case) Or you want something different? Thanks

Comment: Georgy, by spring/portlet specification the default view method is the method annotated with `@RenderMapping`. But I want default method annotated with `@RenderMapping(params="action=someAction")`. How to achieve this?

Comment: @RenderMapping annotated method receive request without render paramters, yes,  I think we can say 'dafault', if you want another method as default, your every request need render parameter action=someAction. But it looks no good. What is your use case? Maybe better solution exists?